# Bing Search API News query language

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

Is there some kind of query language one can use in Bing Search API News to get, for example, only news that contain in their title some words/phrases?
Is there AND, OR, near, etc. that could be used? You can see the operators here, which I *thought* would be working:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795620.aspx

I am talking right now about version 5 and version 7 of the API.

Here's the code I wrote to try this out:

```
# below query is want I would like to have, which doesn't work
query_words = ['announce* near:4 win']

headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'xxxx'}

b = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search'

for w in query_words:
    params = {"q": w, "count": "5", "mkt": "en-US", "category": "business", "freshness": "day"}

    res = requests.get(b, params=params, headers=headers)

    if res.status_code == 200:
        articles = json.loads(res.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for Bing News Search API v5/v7, there is not any operators like your linked for Bing API v2.

Comment: How do you know that? If you check here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v5-reference
and search for Bing Advanced Operators on that page, you'll see that the it references to that same page.

Comment: @elena Please see the item tree, the Bing Advanced Operatores is under the root of Bing API v2 which is old version, not Bing News Search API.

Comment: If you search on the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v5-reference for Bing Advanced Operators, you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

It works, you need to append the operator to query (the **q** parameter). I tried on `curl` with this query:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news/search?q=seattle%2Ccontains:Bellevue" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_KEY"
```

and it modifies results to include "Bellevue" in description. Similarly, **site:** parameter is also working. Seems the operators on the page you mentioned are applicable to v7.